# Unusual behaviour in bash using the -c parameter

Tags: bash, ksh

I came across some unusual behaviour in bash using the `-c` parameter.

If I do the following:

```
bash -c "ping 127.0.0.1 > $HOME/console.log"  &
```

This starts two processes bash and ping:

```
john     18038 17951  0 09:26 pts/14   00:00:00 bash -c ping 127.0.0.1 > /home/john/console.log
john     18039 18038  0 09:26 pts/14   00:00:00 ping 127.0.0.1
```

From the process hierarchy `bash` is the parent process of `ping`.

Now if I kill bash:

```
kill -15 18038
```

And check the process tree again:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
john     17951 30467  0 09:25 pts/14   00:00:00 /bin/bash
john     18039     1  0 09:26 pts/14   00:00:00 ping 127.0.0.1
john     18064 17951  0 09:30 pts/14   00:00:00 ps -f
[1]+  Terminated              bash -c "ping 127.0.0.1 > $HOME/console.log"
```

`bash` is killed but not the child `ping` process. I was expecting that to be killed also.

If I repeat the exact same steps with `ksh –c`, it does kill the `ping` process.

It looks like `bash` does a double fork or something, whereas `ksh` does only an execute without fork.

Comment: the sub processes got orphan, so its parent is now the main process 1.

Comment: Why do you think that killing a parent should kill a child?